# No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `area'

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, casting, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and I'm writing a program that calculates the limit of a function. So given two lists `a` and `b`, a delta `dx = 0.001`, and the limits of integration `l` and `r`, I want to recursively compute the area under the curve with equation:
`a1(x)^b1 + a2(x)^b2 + ... + an(x)bn` where `x` is all the values between `l` an `r` with an increment of `dx` between each value. The technical part isn't that important I guess but it helps to read the code:

```
import Text.Printf (printf)

-- This function should return a list [area].
solve :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Double]
solve l r x y = [area l r x y]

area l r a b = if (l < r)
            then (calc l a b) * 0.001 + (area (l + 1) r a b)
            else (calc r a b) * 0.001


calc n (a:arest) (b:brest) = (fromIntegral(n) ^^ b) * fromIntegral(a) + (calc n arest brest)
calc n [] [] = 0


--Input/Output.
main :: IO ()

main = getContents >>= mapM_ (printf "%.1f\n"). (\[a, b, [l, r]] -> solve l r a b). map (map read. words). lines
```

I get no error with the above code but as soon as I change `area (l + 1) r a b` to `area (l + 0.001) r a b` I get the following error message:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `area'
```

I tried making a new class and having a be an abstract type but that didn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding type signatures to all top-level functions. This will also help you in clarifying which arguments should be integers and which ones should be doubles, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the problem is that `Int` is not a `Fractional` type. In other words, it does not have a value called `0.001` <sup>[note 1]</sup>, but you have requested Haskell to give you such a value in your code.

You are making this request because `0.001` is fed to the `(+)` function with another argument (in this case `l`) which is of type `Int`. This is a problem because the function has type `(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a`: in other words, there are a lot of different functions `(+)` all having the type `a -> a -> a`; one of these functions exists for every type `a` in the `Num` type class.

Since we know that one argument to the function is an `Int`, it follows that we're using the specific function `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`. That is why `l + 0.001` gets weird.

As for solving the problem: You probably wanted `l` and `r` to be of type `Double` (they're left and right bounds on where a number can be?) but if you're sure that they must be `Int`s then you probably meant to write `fromIntegral l + 0.001`.

Side note on style: parentheses in Haskell are always just grouping/precedence, functions are higher precedence than operators which are higher precedence than special forms (`let`, `case`, `if`, `do`), and function application is always left-associative or "greedy nom": a function eats whatever is immediately in front of it. What you have written:

```
(fromIntegral(n) ^^ b) * fromIntegral(a) + (calc n arest brest)
```

is probably better written as:

```
fromIntegral a * fromIntegral n ^^ b + calc n arest brest
```

The parentheses around `calc` are not necessary (because operators like + have lower precedence than function applications), nor are the parentheses around `n` and `a` (because those sub-expressions are indivisible chunks; `fromIntegral(n)` is identical to `fromIntegral (n)` is identical to `fromIntegral n`).

1. As @dfeuer mentions below: secretly, when you write `0.001` it does not have a definite type; rather it is translated to `fromRational 0.001` internally, where the latter `0.001` is a definite value of the definite type `Rational`, just as when you write `4` it is translated to `fromInteger 4` where the latter 4 is a definite value of the definite type `Integer`. The problem is really that there is no `fromRational` function for `Int`, because `Int` is not part of the `Fractional` typeclass which defines `fromRational`. And it's not part of that typeclass because the language designers preferred an error to a silent rounding/dropping of a fraction.

Comment: It seems to me that "does not have an instance for `0.001`" is a bit confusing. What's really going on is that the literal `0.001` really means `fromRational 0.001`. `fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a`, hence the error.